# JavaScript: Iterating through each pixel of a canvas to change color

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on a simple raytracer demo in JavaScript and I figured the first step would be to create a function that goes through every pixel of the image, calls a function that would determine the correct color, and then set the color of the pixel.

As a test I first created a function that fills each pixel with a random color, `fillRandom()`. This seems to work fine. Then I made an identical function meant to fill each pixel with a specific color, `fillSolid()`. This, for reasons which baffle me, does not work. The two functions are identical aside from which function they call to get the desired pixel color, `randomColor()` vs. `getColor()`. Both of those functions return an array with four integers representing RGBA, the only difference is that `getColor()`'s values are hardcoded. But for some reason, the same method that works fine when working with randomly-generated values does nothing when I try to use it to fill in a hardcoded color. I can't figure it out... what am I doing wrong?

```js
var theCanvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');
var context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');


var randomInt = function (max,min) {
    let minV = Math.ceil(min);
    let maxV = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxV-minV+1))+minV;
};

var randomColor = function() {
    let r = randomInt(0,255);
    let g = randomInt(0,255);
    let b = randomInt(0,255);
    let a = 255;
    //let colorString = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
    return [r,g,b,a];
};

var getColor = function() {
    return [255,0,0,255];
}

var fillRandom = function () {

    let imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,theCanvas.width,theCanvas.height);
    let data = imageData.data;

    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let color = randomColor();
        data[i] = color[0];
        data[i+1] = color[1];
        data[i+2] = color[2];
        data[i+3] = 255;
    }

    context.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
};

var fillSolid = function () {

    let imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,theCanvas.width,theCanvas.height);
    let data = imageData.data;

    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let color = getColor();
        data[i] = color[0];
        data[i+1] = color[1];
        data[i+2] = color[2];
        data[i+3] = color[3];
    }

    context.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
};



colorPick = function(event) {
    let x = event.layerX;
    let y = event.layerY;
    let pixel = context.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
    let colorArray = pixel.data;
    let rgba = 'rgba('+colorArray[0]+','+colorArray[1]+','+colorArray[2]+','+(colorArray[3])+')';
    console.log(rgba);
    return rgba
};

theCanvas.addEventListener('click', colorPick);



fillSolid();
```

```css
#theCanvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>CanvasTest01</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="theCanvas" width="500" height="500">Canvas not supported!</canvas>
<script src="CanvasScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the for loop correctly. The loop in incrementing by 1 and replacing the previous values.

Use this in both **fillRandom** and **fillSolid** function. This will set the value of each pixel once with correct values.

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length;i += 4) {
        var color = getColor();
        data[i] = 255;
        data[i+1] = 0;
        data[i+2] = 0;
        data[i+3] = 255;
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! I see now, you have to +4 instead of +1 to jump to the next pixel instead of the next channel of the same pixel.